# Detecting if bootstrap modal window is show don't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have to draw something in bootstrap modal window if user click on button. My code is:

```
$('#button').on('click', function (evt) {
    doSomeCrazyStuff();    
    $('#myModal').modal('show');        
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        alert('Debug');
        drawStuffInModal();            
    });
});
```

For first click everything works fine. But for second click i get two alerts, for third click - three alerts etc.

User can click button only if modal is hidden, so he need to close modal before next drawing.

I found out that a problem is a detecting of modal window state - if I don't use `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {})` but just waiting:

```
$('#button').on('click', function (evt) {
    doSomeCrazyStuff();    
    $('#myModal').modal('show');        
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('Debug');
        drawStuffInModal();            
    }, 500);
});
```

... I always get alert once. It works, but it's very ugly solution.

So my question is: why first code not working properly? I don't want wait *n* miliseconds because in some cases modal can need more time for loading and then user got errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind new event in another click event handler. Click on the `#button` can happen many times, which means that it will bind many similar duplicated events. Just move `shown.bs.modal` event subscription outside:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert('Debug');
    drawStuffInModal();            
});

$('#button').on('click', function (evt) {
    doSomeCrazyStuff();    
    $('#myModal').modal('show');        
});
```

Comment: Right, after moving `shown.bs.modal` outside everything works. Thanks!